# Is there a way to write code that writes code, based on xml information?(Python)

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to automatically generate a python script based on a xml file.
For a simplified example, I want to convert the following xml(#1) to the Python script below(#2).

**#1 Xml File(To Translate)**
[1.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC54z.png)

```
<Code CodeID="1">
  <Settings Setting='OpenFile'>
  </Settings>
  <Properties>
    <Configuration>
      <FieldInfo>
        <Field name="Account" size="255" source="File: 1.xlsx|`Sheet1`" type="V_String" />
        <Field name="PY" source="File: 1.xlsx|`Sheet1`" type="Double" />
        <Field name="CY" source="File: 1.xlsx|`Sheet1`" type="Double" />
      </FieldInfo>
    </Configuration>
  </Properties>
</Code>
```

**#2 The Python Script(Translated)**

```
Import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelFile('1.xlsx') as xlsx:
  df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1')
  df.astype({'Account': 'object', 'PY': 'float64', 'CY': 'float64'}).dtypes
```

I'm quite new to Python and programming, and I want to know where I should start from.
I think I can search and study for the details on how to parse the xml file and so on,
but I don't have a clue on **how to automate the translation process.**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Certainly you can write a code generator based on XML input. However, I'm not sure you need the intermediate step of generating code (unless you plan to modify it by hand later); why not just do operations based on the XML in your program?

Comment: You can read the xml and have a mapping dictionary between the types: {"V_String": "object", ....} and than handle the code as a string, save it to a file. But is it really what you want? Looks more like you want a excel dataframe and do things based on the "hidden values" of that file. If that is the case you dont need a  code generator but a way to read this "hidden values" and process the excel dataframe directly.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for the reply. You've got a point. We're trying to implement things in python for more customization. There are lots of limits on what we can do with the program, and we're trying to study on how we can use python for an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XSL to transform XML to text (eg a python script). XSL is powerful but complex for beginners.

This simple XSL example producs text that is close to what you have put as output

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    
<xsl:template match="/">
Import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelFile('1.xlsx') as xlsx:
  df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1')
  <xsl:for-each select="//Field">
  df.astype({'<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>': 'object',
  </xsl:for-each>
   }).dtypes
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You would need to expand this to deal with all your datatypes and any other object properties. (eg translate 'float64' to 'double'), as part of an XSL solution. However @AKX is correct, you may be better off using the XML to provide parameters that are then processed within your script.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check some material on XSL. It's a big help to know where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create your own generator by parsing XML, and run it inside your main script with subprocess module. You can also use blockly code generator for this kind of job if you wish to make user interface that lets your users create their own macros.

Comment: Can you give any recommendation for documents or reference which I could study?? Thanks.

Comment: In order to clarify blockly side [Blockly Website](https://developers.google.com/blockly) is the best source you can learn blockly. 
You may use **eval** function to evaluate single expression or **exec** function to execute block.
You may use subprocess module to run a python script generated by parsing XML. [Subprocess Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is best place to learn subprocess module.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the materials. Wish you the best.